# AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'associate_iam_instance_profile'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to attach instance profile to an EC2 instance using boto3. I am following boto3 documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.associate_iam_instance_profile

But It fails with below error:

> AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'associate_iam_instance_profile'

Could you please help me with this ?

This is the code snippet

```
import boto3

ec2=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ca-central-1')

response = ec2.associate_iam_instance_profile(IamInstanceProfile={'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/instanceprofilename','Name': 'instanceprofilename'},InstanceId='i-1234567890')
```

A help will be much appreciated.

boto3==1.4.3

Python 3.8.6

Thanks

Comment: Your [version of boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3/releases/tag/1.4.3) is almost 5 years out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to documentation of boto3 version 1.17.112 and you are using a bit outdated boto version. So if there is no version constraint first thing you can do is to update your boto3 version.

```
pip install boto3==1.17.112
```